# 3 Component UIPickerView To Make a 3 Digit Value

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm have a 3 Component UIPickerWheel that allows the user to select a 3 digit number from 0-199 and I want to eventually store that number as a variable.

When I test build the application the hundreds column works as it should. However my single digits column is somehow linked to my tens column, when I update the single digits column the console prints the tens column version of that number (001 prints 10 instead of 1)

What is causing this issue and how do I go about fixing it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I updated my arrays and removing the "0" from the single digits column seemed to be a quick fix, but I'm still curious why this was an issue.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberPicker: UIPickerView!

    var pickerData = [[String]]()

    var hundredsColumn = "0"
    var tensColumn = "0"
    var singleDigits = "0"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.numberPicker.delegate = self
        self.numberPicker.dataSource = self

        pickerData = [
            ["0","1"],
            ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
//Original  ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
            ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
        ]

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerData[component] == pickerData[0] {
            hundredsColumn = pickerData[0][row]
        }
        else if pickerData[component] == pickerData[1] {
            tensColumn = pickerData[1][row]
        }
        else {
            singleDigits = pickerData[component][row]
        }

        let total = (Int(hundredsColumn)! * 100 + (Int(tensColumn)! * 10) + (Int(singleDigits)! * 1)
        print(total)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working ,there is no need to convert string to integers and add you directly append strings then you can convert it into integer

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if pickerData[component] == pickerData[0] {
            hundredsColumn = pickerData[0][row]
        }
        else if pickerData[component] == pickerData[1] {
            tensColumn = pickerData[1][row]
        }
        else {
            singleDigits = pickerData[component][row]
        }
        let totalIs = hundredsColumn + tensColumn + singleDigits
        print("\(totalIs)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification NSLog. Any idea why it doesn't work correctly when pickerData[1] and pickerData[2] contain the same string values?

Comment: i don't know whats happening let total = (hundredsColumn*100)+(tensColumn*10)+(singleDigits*1) this is also working ,I converted hundredsColumn, tensColumn and singleDigits to Int then it is working fine .

Comment: it seems to work only when my second and third pickerData arrays don't match. if they are both ["0", ... "9"] my single digits column doesn't work correctly.